# Combine multiple rows in pandas dataframe and create new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dynamic number of columns in my dataframe for each row and a single record can go for more than 1 row. First 2 columns are the key columns. If the key columns are matching, i have to append each row of data into a single row and create as much columns as required for appending.

Input is below (dataframe) c1 in a column c2 in a column etc...

```
row 1: A 1 c1 c2 c3.. c20
row 2: A 1 c21....c25
row 3. A 1 c26.... c35
row 4: A 2 d1 d2... d21
row 5: A 2 d22....d27
```

I tried using df.groupby(___first 2 column names____).first().reset_index() which returns only first row as we are using first(). is there any function to do this in python

output required: (dataframe)

```
row 1: A 1 c1 c2...c35 (each value in 1 column)
row 2: A 2 d1...d27 (each value in 1 column)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for series of counter, then [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and last flatten `MultiIndex` in list comprehension:

```
print (df)
       a  b    c    d    e    f
row1:  A  1   c1   c2   c3  c20
row2:  A  1  c21  c22  c23  c24
row3.  A  1  c26  c27  c28  c29
row4:  A  2   d1   d2  d21  d22
row5:  A  2  d22  d27  d28  d29

s = df.groupby(['a','b']).cumcount()

df1 = df.set_index(['a', 'b', s]).unstack().sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
df1.columns = [f'{x}{y}' for x, y in df1.columns]
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
   a  b  c0  d0   e0   f0   c1   d1   e1   f1   c2   d2   e2   f2
0  A  1  c1  c2   c3  c20  c21  c22  c23  c24  c26  c27  c28  c29
1  A  2  d1  d2  d21  d22  d22  d27  d28  d29  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```